# Como hago la union de conjuntos

Tags: c

Tengo la funcion hebrada para hacer la distancia de Jaccard, que es la division de interseccion de conjuntos y la union.
La interseccion me sale pero la union no.
Lo que hacen los hilos es que cada hilo coge 1/4 parte del vectorA y de lo compara con todo el vectorB

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 4

typedef struct interval{
    double distanciaJ;
    double k,u;
    int ini;
    int fin;
} aux;

double* vectorA;
double* vectorB;
int sizeA=5,sizeB=6;

void *funcion(void *threadid)
{
    int ini1,fin1, itera,interseccion,uni;
    aux *inter;
    inter = ((aux *) (threadid));
    itera = inter->distanciaJ;
    ini1 = inter->ini;
    fin1 = inter->fin;
    interseccion=inter->k;
    uni=inter->u;

    int i=0,j=0;
    double interseccionN=0,unionN=0;

    for(i=ini1;i<fin1;i++){     
        for(int j=0;j<sizeB;j++)
            if(vectorA[i]==vectorB[j]){
                interseccionN++;    
            }
    }

    inter->k=interseccionN;
    unionN=p+sizeB; 
    inter->u=unionN;
    inter->distanciaJ=interseccionN/unionN;     

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    long t;
    double distanciaTotal=0;
    int i,resto=sizeA%NUM_THREADS;
    vectorA=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*sizeA);
    vectorB=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*sizeB);

    for(i=0;i<sizeA;i++){
        vectorA[i]=i;
        printf("%.2f",vectorA[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<sizeB;i++){
        vectorB[i]=2*i;
        printf("%.2f",vectorB[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    aux param[NUM_THREADS];
    for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++) {        
        param[t].distanciaJ = 0;
        param[t].k=0;
        param[t].u=0;
        param[t].ini= t*(sizeA/NUM_THREADS)+(t<resto?t:resto);
        param[t].fin=param[t].ini+(sizeA/NUM_THREADS)+(t<resto);
        //printf("Creating thread %ld\n", t);
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, funcion, (void *) &param[t]);

        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    double aux22=0,aux23;
    for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++) {
        rc = pthread_join(threads[t],NULL);
        distanciaTotal+=param[t].distanciaJ;
        aux22+=param[t].k;
        aux23+=param[t].u;
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }

    }
    printf("La interseccion es %.2f\n",aux22);
    printf("La union es %.2f\n",aux23);


    printf("La distancia de Jaccard es %.2f\n",distanciaTotal); 

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `p`? La usas pero no la declararas en ningún lado

Comment: Es un errata...en secuencial seria union=sizeA+sizeb-interseccion. Es una manera pero haciendo eso con hilos hae la union de todo con todo, y añade tmb los repetidos.